# Iphone geo location permission check

Tags: iphone

Hi i have a quick question about the iphone (iOS) geolocation api's. Currenly i have a map in my application and the operating system will ask the user if it wants to allow the use of geolocations. Now thats all nice but the thing is i want to change my app when geolocations is allowed to a so called "Geo location" mode where new options are available or "standard" mode with less ui elements when permissions are not granted.

What can i use to check if permission is granted?. So basicaly is that an api that tells me permission granted yes or no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `CLLocationManager`'s `locationServicesEnabled` property to check the system-wide availability. Use your `CLLocationManagerDelegate`'s `locationManager: didFailWithError:` method and check for a `kCLErrorDenied` error to see if the user denied location services.

Read Apple's `[CLLocationManagerDelegate` docs][1](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didFailWithError:) for more.

Comment: the locationServicesEnabled property is deprecated, use if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] == NO) and if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)